# Сортировка комнат по количеству пользователей

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый вечер, есть код делающий запрос к таблице `user_online`, в ней содержаться строки: `uid | time (time добавляется time() + 3000) | rid (rooms id)`, и таблица `rooms` (Комнаты). Когда делаю вывод, мне хотелось бы чтобы выводило комнаты не по порядку добавленных id `ORDER BY id`, а по кол-ву пользователей в комнате... То есть, делаем запрос к базе `$count = $db->row("SELECT count(id) as count FROM user_online WHERE time > '".time()."' AND rid = '".$rooms['id']."'");` Соответственно мы узнаем, сколько пользователей онлайн в данной комнате, но как дальше правильно вывести, чтобы именно выводило от большего кол-во пользователей в комнате к меньшему. До кого не дошло, к примеру, в комнате 1 - 2 пользователя, в комнате 2 - 3 пользователя, в комнате 3 - 1 пользователь, соответственно, 1 показанная комната будет с id - 2, далее с id - 1, и последняя комната будет иметь id - 3

Comment: Неправильно выбирать отдельным запросом `$count ` (причем я уверен у вас там наверняка цикл висит), если можно в одном запросе все выбрать приджойнив таблицу и выбрать по `GROUP BY`....... Но лучше бы вы визуально предоставили структуру таблиц. И немного данных в нем. Тем более есть инструмент, который может помочь с этим: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Через `GROUP BY` вы определенно можете решить задачу, это будет быстрее нескольких запросов в цикле. Но если данных не слишком мало, то группировка тоже будет подтормаживать. Быстро будет только если где-то хранить готовые счетчики с количеством. Счетчики можете менять там, где определяете состояние online.

Comment: То есть, как я понял, добавлять в таблицу rooms еще и кол-во пользователь в комнате? И потом уже обновлять строку? И немного дошло, делаем запрос на вывод -> далее считаем сколько пользователей онлайн в данной комнате, обновляем в таблице rooms кол-во пользователей онлайн и уже потом делаем вывод... Мысль моя в правильное русло идет?

Comment: Вам же еще в первом сообщении написал...напишите стрктуры обеих таблиц...и свой код, где пытаетесь что-то выводить (не только `$count ` а немного больше кода хочется увидеть)..........структуру можно и тут показать а можно зайти на http://sqlfiddle.com/  задать обе таблицы и данные в нем и в вопросе добавить ссылку на этот фиддл..... а так - только гадать можно

Comment: rooms: `id | uid | name | deleted | status | date`. user_online: `id | uid | time` `$chats = $db->rows("SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE deleted = 'f' AND status = 't' ORDER BY id DESC");

 foreach($chats as $id => $chat):

  $counts = $db->row("SELECT count(id) as count FROM user_online WHERE cid = ? AND time < ?", Array($chat['id'], time()));

  $json['rooms'][] = Array('id' => intval($chat['id']), 'name' => $chat['name'], 'users' => $counts['count'], 'date' => $chat['date']);

 endforeach;` die(json_encode($json));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно получить список комнат с количеством онлайн-пользователей в них, отсортированных по этому количеству при помощи одного двухтабличного запроса

```
SELECT
  r.*,
  COUNT(u.id) AS total
FROM
  rooms AS r
LEFT JOIN
  user_online AS u
ON
  r.id = u.rid
WHERE
  u.time > NOW()
GROUP BY
  r.id
ORDER BY
  total DESC
```